# What changes occur in Detroit and Heng Sha between trips to those locations?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I noticed when I returned to Detroit that some odd things had changed, but this was a very cursory look, so I don't know for sure:

- Broken walls were repaired.
- At least some computer terminals were un-hacked, even though I'd gotten every one available on the first run. Door panels were always still hacked.
- The available areas were slightly different - i.e. the police station was locked up the second time but a new area was available as part of the main quest.
- No new items seemed to be available in the areas common to both visits.

What, specifically, changes in Detroit and Heng Sha between the first and second visits to those locations?

Comment: vendor stocks change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In general:

  - All objects returned to default positions.
  - All broken objects regenerated.
  - All bodies removed (☠ and Zzz).
  - Some new items spawn.
  - Merchants restock
- Detroit

  - Some areas locked off (police station, Sarif HQ main entrance)
- Hengsha

  - The Hive is locked down.
  - Hung Hua hotel is almost empty.
  - Belltower guards looking for you.
  - Alice Pod Gardens merchant moves to Youzhao district.

Comment: Do you happen to know if terminals are reset to the unhacked state, or was I just imagining that?

Comment: A couple get un-hacked. Not sure if it is a bug or scripted.

Comment: I think some break-able walls (such as those in the sewers) get repaired, although the goodies behind them aren't regenerated.

Comment: The walls count as "broken objects".